# Using a shell commands in c++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, escaping

Here's a terminal command:

```
awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)
```

Here's my code:

```
class CSystemInfo{
public:
    std::string free_ram(){
        std::string s;
        FILE *in;
        char buff[512];
        //here is a prepared string (but with an error)
        if(!(in = popen("awk '/^Mem/ {print $4 \"\\t\"}' <(free -m)","r"))){
        return "";  
        }
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            cout << s;
            s=s+buff;
        }
        pclose(in);
        return s;
       }
};
    CSystemInfo info;
    std::string ram = info.free_ram();
    cout << ram;
```

The above code, when run, returns this message:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How can I place the '/' symbol, for this command to work correctly?

Comment: Looks like default shell - `sh` - is not supporting `<(free -m)` syntax. Consider invoking `bash`.

Comment: in terminal this command looks nice

Comment: Your teminal shell could be `bash` that *supports* this syntax, while `popen` runs in `sh`, more primitive, low-level shell. Try `echo $0`. I have just tried running your command in `sh`, it failed with the same message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in C++. You are invoking your command with `popen`, and `popen` runs your command in `sh` shell, that does not support `<()` syntax, while in your terminal you are having `bash`, `zsh` or any other shell, that does support `<()` syntax.

**Edit:** Better choise! Use pipes!

```
popen("free -m | awk ...")
```

**Original answer, not working!:** Try invoking `bash` in `popen`:

```
bash -c "awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)"
```

in code:

```
popen("bash -c \"awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)\"")
```

Comment: Memory:       3398       2848        550        380        209        959               
`{print $4}` doesn't work

Comment: Works for me (I just changed `Mem` to `Пам` because I'm running russian localization). I added one new option to answer, check it out.

Comment: I use it too. But the best, what I see is `Память:       3398       2785        613        339        212        918`

Comment: OK, I see, my original answer is wrong, use pipe option